# Error With PHP7 and SQL Server on Windows

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am getting "Fatal error: Invalid handle returned. in" in PHP 7 while trying to connect with SQL Server.

**I have already tried below option**

[Error connecting to MSSQL with SQLSrv and PHP 5.4.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651646/error-connecting-to-mssql-)
[Unable to connect to SQL Server with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222539/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-with-php)

I am using below code:

```
try {  
   $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server=(10.10.10.222\sql2008r2);Database=test",'sa', 'sipl@123');   
   $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
}  

catch( PDOException $e ) {  
   die( "Error connecting to SQL Server" );   
}  

echo "Connected to SQL Server\n";  

$query = 'SELECT *FROM atlas_positions';   
$stmt = $conn->query( $query );   
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){   
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $row );   
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Your views will be beneficial for me.

Comment: You can't take this error with this code while trying to connect but you can get while trying to run sql. In that case, is it can be the mistake in __$query__ variable? ''SELECT __(star)FROM__ atlas_positions'' did u put a space between __(star)__ and __from__ ?

Comment: just remove your connecting informations from comment

Comment: I run this in query browser it's working.

Answer (score 3):

Try "ConnectionPooling=0" in DSN, it worked for me.

```
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server=(10.10.10.222\sql2008r2);Database=test;ConnectionPooling=0",'sa', 'sipl@123');
```

(My answer is based on @maydimanche's answer [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38517951/2022457))